# camel salesforce connector how use composite graph?

Tags: java, apache-camel, salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-communities

I'm using in my project the camel-salesforce-connetor 3.7.2 .
I need to invoke a composite graph api on salesforce but the only method available on documentation are :

**composite** - submit up to 25 possibly related REST requests and receive individual responses. It’s also possible to use "raw" composite without limitation.

**composite-tree** - create up to 200 records with parent-child relationships (up to 5 levels) in one go

**composite-batch** - submit a composition of requests in batch

how can I invoke a composite-graph using the connector?

Thanks